# PhP/MySQL/Javascript: URL changing based on MySQL query (javascript?) and load data from this URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, url

**Scenario:**
I have a MySQL database called Data. It contains 100 rows with columns: `ID`, `URL`, `Title`, `UniqueKey`.
Each item is like this:
`ID`: 353
`URL`: http://www.test.com
`Title`: Test site
`UniqueKey`: 3tA5gQ

The `UniqueKey` is randomly generated for each item and unique.

**What I want:**

A visitor visits my website: website.com/data/. I want them to click a BUTTON that loads a RANDOM item from the MySQL database into the page. It must show in the URL like this: webiste.com/data/3tA5gQ (in short, it must add the UniqueKey to the URL).
 - On Refresh, it should keep the item currently showing.
 - The URL is unique; when someone links the URL website.com/data/3tA5gQ to someone else, it should show the corresponding item in the MySQL database (based on the `UniqueKey`).

**What I have so far:**

on my index.hp in website.com/data/ I load my scripts up top:

```
include ('database.php');
include ('custom_search.php');
```

**database.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "data";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$pietje = floatVal('0.'.rand(1, 9));
```

**custom_search.php**
Based on `$pietje`, it will load data from the MySQL database:

```
if ($pietje < 0.9) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data order by RAND()";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

on my **index.php** I can load the data like this:
    $row['UniqueKey'];

With JavaScript, I can create a hash in the URL:

```
<script>
    parent.location.hash = "!<?php echo $row['UniqueKey']?>";
</script>
```

But now it looks like this: website.com/data/#3tA5gQ

---

**My questions:**

- How can I most efficiently change the URL? Right now it shows a `hash #` due to the javascript, but I don't want the hash.
- How can I load an item from the MySQL database ONLY by clicking a button?
- If the URL shows website.com/data/3tA5gQ, how can I make sure that visitors can share this link and the data corresponding to the `UniqueKey 3tA5gQ` is shown to them as well? (so, the corresponding `url/title/id`)

  I have NO idea how to fix this. I'm lost in a jungle of code and google suggestions. Please help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: <?php header('Location: http://www.example.com/' + $row['UniqueKey']); ?> (or something like that :-)

Comment: @Nomistake thanks, but that is only with redirecting; I don't want it to redirect. I want the page to load a random MySQL item and then push it to the URL; and this same URL UniqueKey should be a link that people can share (as in, showing the same content due to the same unique key). I have no clue how to fix this..